# iPhone Screen Shadow

Tags: iphone, screen

iPhone 4S suddenly have screen shadow, it start when i charge my phone, and now it didn't disappear.

Is this software defect? since i just update my phone to iOS 7.0.6 (two days ago as i remember).

Here is the actual photo of the shadow defect.

[image: actual photo]

And here is the screenshot taken from iPhone (show now shadow)

[image: screenshot]

Which make me afraid if this hardware defect because of age :(
My phone age is 2 or 3 years, it's new purchased. Never jailbrake. It is sad if iphone screen can only hold off 3 years (-.-")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a clear case of [LCD image persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_persistence) which might go away in a few hours or day or might require service to exchange the panel if those changes are permanent. Depending on how long the image was static - you probably won't see the ghosting after it's off for a few hours or the panel gets used to the new pattern you are displaying on those pixels (retaining that image rather than the old one).

Software defects would show up in the screen capture and this is a very common limitation of plasma and LCD displays due to the physics behind how they produce and filter light.

Comment: Maybe, This problem is still occur, let's wait few days and see what happen. Anyway i notice the problem not occur few millisecond after i turn on the screen. (video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6wbTiBHjcY)

Comment: Update info, the screen now is fix itself :D

Comment: @GusDeCooL Glad it was temporary. That's the typical case, but hardware can fail as well..